# Methods to get the screen resolution before a web page is getting loaded

Tags: javascript

I want to know the different methods to recognize the screen resolution.

Like

Desktop Resolutions

Tablet Resolutions

Mobile Phones etc;

Comment: `screen.width`/`screen.height`

Comment: What do you mean by "before a web page is loaded"? Before anything is loaded, you cannot execute any script.

Answer (score 0):

Starters... You can't execute any query or anything without your page being loaded. Aside that, there are several ways you can check your screen resolutions. You could use the CSS media queries or JavaScript.

See the links below for more insight.

- http://css-tricks.com/resolution-specific-stylesheets/
- http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/

There are other available resources online so just make some extra searches and you'll be good to go.